# Project Euler problem #731

Tags: real-numbers, project-euler

In this Poject Euler probelm < https://projecteuler.net/problem=731 > I'm asked to find the 10 decimal digits from the nth number onward in the decimal expansion of the infinte serie : $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{10^{3^k}3^k}$$  which is equal to the stoneham number $\alpha_{10,3}$

My try was : take i such that $3^i$ > n then take all the fractions of the form $$a_k=\frac1{3^k}$$ such that k in [1..(i-1)] .

Then for all the fractions : take the the 10 decimal digits from the nth digit onward and sum them up

This method works fine for A(100) , but it is clear that for large n , this method will not work due to carries addition issue . For example for n=$10^{16}$: we have to sum the 10 decimal digits from the $10^{16}$th number onward of those fractions :  $$a_k=\frac1{3^k}$$   such that k in [1..33] . Is there another method to attack this problem ?

Python code for the case n = 100 :

```
a='3' # repeating decimal of 1/3

a*=200

b='1' # repeating deciaml of 1/9

b*=200

c='037' # repeating deciaml of 1/27

c*=200

d='012345679' repeating decimal of 1/81 

d*=120

for k in range(99,99+10):

     print(int(a[k])+int(b[k])+int(c[k])+int(d[k]))
```

Stop at $\frac1{81}$ because $10^{243}$ in the denominator will gives us 243 zeros after the decimal point

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say in the description of your method. If you have written code to implement this, it would be helpful if you could edit your post to include this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $i$ be the smallest integer for which $3^i > n$. What we are after are the $10$ digits from the $n$th number onward in the *finite* sum
$$
S_1 = \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{10^{3^k}3^k}.
$$
Equivalently, we want the first 10 digits after the decimal point in the number $10^{n-1}S_1$, which is equal to
$$
S_2 = \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{10^{n - 3^k - 1}}{3^k}.
$$
That is, we only want the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $S_2$ expanded to $10$ digits.

---

Here's code that implements the idea I had in mind:

```
import math

n = 10**8

m = int(math.log(n,3))
tot = 0
for k in range(1,m+1):
    phi = 2*3**(k-1)
    exp = n - 3**k - 1
    exp %= phi
    num = 10**exp
    num %= 3**k
    tot += num/3**k
tot -= int(tot)
print(int(tot*10**10))
```

Although it technically works, this method is problematic because $10^{n - 3^k - 1}$ is very large. Instead, we can efficiently compute $10^{n - 3^k - 1} \bmod 3^k$. For instance:

```
import math

# SET VALUE OF n HERE
n = 10**8

m = int(math.log(n,3))
tot = 0
for k in range(1,m+1):
    den = 3**k
    exp = n - den - 1
    num = pow(10,exp,den)
    tot += num/den       # python 2: tot += float(num)/den
tot -= int(tot)
print(int(tot*10**10))
```

Comment: @meh98 You can't calculate it directly in this way. I've added code that does what I had in mind, and I've confirmed that it works for $10^2$ and $10^8$.

Comment: @meh98 Maybe you had a problem before because of python2 vs python3. I've added something about that in the comments to the final version

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a nice solution

Comment: @m About the question you had asked: the point is that $(a\bmod b)/b$ is the fractional part of $a/b$