# Project Euler #731_part2

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

In this link : [Project Euler problem #731](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886780/project-euler-problem-731) , I got a nice solution for my question but i'm missing a crucial part .

I want to get an explanation of this part of the answer : [image]

My question : Why did we calculate the numerator $mod$ $3^k$ ? I would like to get a demonstration , because i'm not familiar with modular arithmetic

Comment: Why not ask the person who posted that solution?

Comment: Project Euler problems are meant to be solved by *you*. They are *not* meant to be asked at sites you perceive as "do my homework, NOW!" sites. And if you are not familiar with modular arithmetics, you are not likely to solve quite a few Project Euler problems. That might be a stimulus to learn it... or it might be not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because MSE shouldn't support cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author of the answer states: "We only need the fractional part of $S_2$": Any number $n$ can be written as $n=m+r$ where $m$ is divisible by $3^k$ and $r=n\mod 3^k$. But $\frac{n}{3^k} = \frac{m}{3^k} + \frac{r}{3^k}$.
Since $m$ is divisible by $3^k$ the first summand on the rhs is an integer and thus does not contribute to the fractional part of $\frac{n}{3^k}$. So it suffices to compute the $n\mod 3^k$. In this particular instance that seems to be more efficient computationally. EDIT: For a demonstration check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Examples) or google